# Generated binding class that only takes a LayoutInflater as its sole argument

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, data-binding, android-databinding

The [generated binding class](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/generated-binding#create) from the Android Data Binding library has different versions of the `inflate` method: One that looks like the usual `LayoutInflater.inflate` method that takes a `viewGroup` and `attachToRoot` parameter, and one that only takes a `LayoutInflater` and nothing else.

[image]

The documentation doesn't explain the difference between the two and unfortunately Android Studio doesn't let me step through the source code of `inflate` so that I could figure out which values it is using internally for `viewGroup` and `attachToRoot`. When placing fragments on the screen, I notice no difference between the two. When I use it for RecyclerView items, the `inflate` method that only takes a `LayoutInflater` doesn't place the items properly.

So my question is: What values for `viewGroup` and `attachToRoot` does this method use internally and is it appropriate to use it in a fragment's `onCreateView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What values for viewGroup and attachToRoot does this method use internally?

The parameters mirror those on `LayoutInflater` where `root: ViewGroup` is described as

> Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy (if *attachToRoot* is true), or else simply **an object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy** (if *attachToRoot* is false.) This value may be `null`.

Source: [LayoutInflater docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)), emphasis mine.

The `root` argument is used to [generate `LayoutParams`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android10-release:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java;l=669) from the `layout_*` XML attributes for the inflated view. Each layout may understand a different set of layout attributes and define a different set of defaults. That's why you should always pass `root`. The only place where that's not possible is when inflating dialog views.

The one-parameter method on the binding doesn't provide a `root` layout, so no `LayoutParams` are generated for the inflated view at this point. In other words, `inflate(inflater) == inflate(inflater, null, false)`.

If a view doesn't have `LayoutParams` **when you attach it**, its new parent layout will generate default using [`generateDefaultLayoutParams`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android10-release:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java;l=4870).

If you follow what `generateDefaultLayoutParams` does in `RecyclerView`, [it's delegated to the layout manager](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.java;l=4599;drc=0f516b7c034efa8dc02da40ca6555f04cbe2ccf8). Now look at the default [`LayoutParams` provided by `LinearLayoutManager`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager.java;l=199;drc=80a136a0f0964ed9da8eaf868a144948017889f9):

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
    return new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}
```

Typically, if you plan to have a vertical list you would set `android:layout_width="match_parent"` on the items. But when you attach a view without `LayoutParams` to a `RecyclerView`, it gets both dimensions set to `wrap_content`. That's why your layout looks wrong when inflated with `root == null`.

---

> Is it appropriate to use [the one-parameter `inflate` method] in a fragment's `onCreateView`?

The one-parameter inflater is OK to use for inflating dialog views, where there's no parent/container/root view.

Typically, you would attach a fragment to a `FrameLayout` or `FragmentContainerView` (which extends `FrameLayout`). `FrameLayout` generates `LayoutParams` with `match_parent` width and height. If that's OK for your fragment, you can use the one-parameter `inflate` method on your binding.

Otherwise always use the provided/known parent to generate proper `LaoyutParams`. Don't rely on the default `LayoutParams` provided by the container you're attaching a view to, even if it's the same layout. You defined some layout params in XML, you'll want them to be respected.

Remember, there is some fragment lifecycle ceremony involved if you hold a reference to the binding.

Here's my current setup with fragments + view bindings:

```
// Nullable reference so we can use it later and clear it later.
private var binding: ExampleFragmentBinding? = null

private fun requireBinding() = checkNotNull(binding)

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Respect the XML layout params.
    val binding = ExampleFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    this.binding = binding
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val binding = requireBinding()
    // Do stuff with the views.
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    // Detach view hierarchy reference from fragment, which may prevent memory leaks.
    this.binding = null

    super.onDestroyView()
}
```

Comment: But you are using the version that takes a `ViewGroup` and `attachToRoot` in your example. I think I made my question not clear enough. The binding class has an `inflate` method that **only** takes a `LayoutInflater` and nothing else. How does it differ from the one you're using?

Comment: Oh, sorry, `Binding.inflate(inflater)` is `Binding.inflate(inflater, null, false)`. Does the rest make sense now?

Comment: Basically, forget that the one-parameter method exists. You'll always have a container/root/parent layout that 1) will correctly parse layout params 2) the view will be attached to. `attachToRoot` should always be `false`, otherwise the method would return the parent layout instead of the view you just inflated - 99% of the time that's not what you want. One exception is inflating layouts for dialogs where there is no parent view.

Comment: But when I used it in a fragment I couldn't see any difference. All the layout attributes worked properly.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're putting the fragment in a `FrameLayout` and [`FrameLayout` generates default `LayoutParams` with `match_parent` width and height](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android10-release:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/FrameLayout.java;l=154).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin, use this version only if `layoutId` is unknown in advance:

```
private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val binding : MyFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.my_fragment, container, false)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
    binding.myViewModel = viewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    return binding.root
}
```

otherwise use the generated `Binding` class inflate method:

```
lateinit var binding: MyFragmentBinding 
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val binding = MyFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}
```

Update:

> So my question is: What values for viewGroup and attachToRoot does
>   this method use internally and is it appropriate to use it in a
>   fragment's onCreateView?

When you call `inflate` with only `inflater` as paramter, `null` and `false` are the default values passed
ie. when you do:

```
val binding: MyFragmentBinding = MyFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater)
```

it is similar to doing:

```
 val binding: MyFragmentBinding = MyFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, null, false)
```

Comment: The documentation for `DataBindingUtil` says to prefer the generated binding class over `DataBindingUtil` unless you don't know the layout id in advance

Comment: Thank you. But the question was what is the difference between the `inflate` method that only takes a `LayoutInflater` vs the one you're using.

Comment: @FlorianWalther I have updated the answer, I think the [official docs for LayoutInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)) are quite self explanatory what is `root` and `attachToRoot` and these are not related in anyway to data binding.